# Is there winapi to add permissions to memory pages instead of changing it?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

I always use VirtualProtect to change memory pages permissions, but is there a way to just add, for example, PAGE_READWRITE to some page that I dont know what other permissions it has?

Of course i can check it myself with VirtualQuery, but is there easier way to just add permissions?

thanks

Comment: Looks like VirtualProtect returns ... "A pointer to a variable that receives the previous access protection value of the first page in the specified region of pages. If this parameter is NULL or does not point to a valid variable, the function fails." ... So you can probably call it twice and OR the value you want to add

Comment: Why do you ask? You know that there isn't such a function. You can tell that from MSDN. You already know how to solve your problem.

Comment: I thought there may be winapi that i dont know about

Comment: They all begin with the word Virtual. It's easy to see there isn't one. If you want to write a helper function that's easy.

Answer (score 3):

no, not exist such api. you can only direct set the memory protection. and look for constant - this is not flags (bitmasks):

```
#define PAGE_NOACCESS           0x01    
#define PAGE_READONLY           0x02    
#define PAGE_READWRITE          0x04    
#define PAGE_WRITECOPY          0x08    
#define PAGE_EXECUTE            0x10    
#define PAGE_EXECUTE_READ       0x20    
#define PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE  0x40    
#define PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  0x80
```

say for example `PAGE_READONLY | PAGE_EXECUTE != PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` (0x12 != 0x20)